# traversing through div(s) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added several `div` in body of my html page. Next, I have added certain buttons and associated click functions in jQuery . Depending upon the button pressed the background-color of a `div` element is changed. The problem occurs at *terminals*. After it reached the first(or last) I want to cycle through the next element. Below is what have I tried. It seems there's a problem in `if()` part of my code. Please point what might be wrong here. [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalkrishna85/3eutny3m/)

I fail to understand if I can assign as :

```
$curr = $("div").first();
```

then why can't I compare as :

```
if($curr === $("div").first())
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div><span>has child</span></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div id="start"></div>
<div></div>

<p>Go to First <input type="button" id="first" value="First" /></p>
<p>Go to Next <input type="button" id="next" value="Next"/></p>
<p>Go to Prev <input type="button" id="prev" value="Prev" /></p>
<p>Go to Last <input type="button" id="last" value="Last" /></p>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px blue solid;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  span {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  p {
    clear: left;
    margin: 10px;
  }
```

JS:

```
var $curr = $( "#start" );
$curr.css( "background", "#f99" );

$( "#first" ).click(function() {
      $curr = $("div").first();
      $( "div" ).css( "background", "" );
      $curr.css( "background", "#f99" );  
});

$( "#prev" ).click(function() {
    if($curr === $("div").first()){
        alert("cycling through...");
        $curr = $("div").last();
        $( "div" ).css( "background", "" );
        $curr.css( "background", "#f99" ); 
    }else{
        $curr = $curr.prev();
        $( "div" ).css( "background", "" );
        $curr.css( "background", "#f99" );  
    }
});

$( "#next" ).click(function() {
    if($curr === $("div").last()) {
        alert("cycling through...");
        $curr = $("div").first();
        $( "div" ).css( "background", "" );
        $curr.css( "background", "#f99" ); 
    }else {
        $curr = $curr.next();
        $( "div" ).css( "background", "" );
        $curr.css( "background", "#f99" );
    }
});

$( "#last" ).click(function() {
      $curr = $("div").last();
      $( "div" ).css( "background", "" );
      $curr.css( "background", "#f99" );  
});
```

UPDATE 01: 
Also after it reaches the last element pressing Next button colors the buttons too. I want instead the first div to be colored and not the buttons. Why are buttons getting colored ? They are not inside any div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can use a CSS class to add / remove background class as this will be easy to identify the current element. As `is(':last')` or `is(':first')` not working because there is not wrapping element for all `div` and they are inside `body` directly. hence you can make use of index of the element to find if it is last or first.

CSS

```
.color{background-color: #f99;}
```

jQuery

```
var $curr = $( "#start" );
$curr.addClass( "color" );
var total =  $curr.siblings("div").length;

$( "#first" ).click(function() {
      $curr = $("div").first();
      $( "div.color" ).removeClass("color" );
      $curr.addClass( "color" );  
});

$( "#prev" ).click(function() {

    if($curr.index()==0) {
        $curr = $('div').last();
    }
    else
    {
      $curr = $curr.prev();  
    }
    $( "div.color" ).removeClass("color" );
    $curr.addClass( "color" ); 
});

$( "#next" ).click(function() {
    if($curr.index()==total) {
        $curr = $('div').first();
    }
    else
    {
      $curr = $curr.next();  
    }
    $( "div.color" ).removeClass("color" );
    $curr.addClass( "color" ); 
});

$( "#last" ).click(function() {
      $curr = $("div").last();
      $( "div.color" ).removeClass("color" );
      $curr.addClass( "color" );  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3eutny3m/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

After studying more I came to know that the correct syntax is using `is()` function and not the `===` operator.

CORRECT SYNTAX:

```
$curr.is( $("div:first") )
```

WRONG ATTEMPT:

```
$curr === $("div").first()
```

Here's the [forked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalkrishna85/oaodmtjt/)